# Google sheets, how do I combine data from two cells, where there is a URL (web-link) in the cells, without loosing the link(url)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

I have tried to write a custom function in google sheets.

I tried to create a function to joint the content of two cells. It works for text, however it does not work if the text contains a web-link (URL). The link is removed.

The code

```
function combine(...theArgs) {
  var result ="";
  var is_first = true;
  theArgs.forEach( function (value, index){
    if (! is_first) {
      result += "\n\n";
    }
    is_first=false;
    result += value;
  });
  return result;
}
```

Usage `=combine(ref, ref)` e.g. `=combine(a1,b1)`

I tried to use `=hyperlink(url,text)`, this can combine the text and link from different cells, so I then tried `=hyperlink(url1, text1) & hyperlink(url2, text2)`. The `&` is demoting the link to text (removes the url).

Acceptable answers: 
 - How to get a custom function to work.
 - Use of built in function.
 - Something else that has the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It don't think that it's possible to do what you are looking to do with a custom function, as in order to keep the hyperlinks, you will need to set the cell content by using Class RichText which, as far as I know, is not a supported data type for custom functions.

The supported data types for custom function output are `string`, `number`, `boolean`, `Date` and `Array` of any of the mentioned data types.